# BelongsToMany by array values in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

How do I store data in `users.sport_id`:

User class:

```
public function sport() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Sport');
}
```

Where sports table has:

```
+----+------------+
| id |    sport   |
+----+------------+
| 1  |  baseball  |
+----+------------+
| 2  | basketball |
+----+------------+
```

Do I add to `user.sport_id = 1,2` or save it as array `[1,2]` and  use `$casts = ['sport_id'=>'array'];`

Comment: It sounds like you should be using a `belongsToMany` relationship (many-to-many). https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Okay I need middle table but what do I store in  users table role_id column?

Comment: What's the role_id?

Comment: Ohh this is different for this I dont need role_id inside users table just id from user which is connected to user_id inside role_user table and role id is connected to role_id... And I can add as much as I want rows with user_id 1 and different role_id values and all together get me user roles. Right? :D

Comment: Yeah, that should do the trick.